# How can I align gridlines with dots in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
     {
"chart": {
    "type": "spline",
    "panning": true,
    "animation": false,
    "reflow": false,
    "events": {}
},
"plotOptions": {
    "series": {
        "lineWidth": 3,
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "states": {
            "hover": {
                "enabled": false,
                "marker": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }
        },
        "point": {
            "events": {}
        }
    }
},
"xAxis": {
    "categories": [] // "00:00" to "23:00",
    "gridLineWidth": 1,
    "gridLineColor": "#efefef",
    "minRange": 5,
    "lineWidth": 3
},
"yAxis": {
    "title": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "gridLineWidth": 1,
    "gridLineColor": "#efefef",
    "style": {
        "display": "none"
    },
    "minRange": 6
}
  }
```

[image: Lines not aligned to dots]

Is it in anyway possible for me to align the dots with the x-axis gridlines in the background? I have attached the Highcharts object that I have so far.

Thanks

Comment: could you update your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ate7ur9z/ or provide other your separate code like this to better understand.

Comment: Done, I see it works how I want it to on that fiddle, so I guess now the question is how I do the inverse and get the points off-beat with dots (or numbers at the bottom, more precisely)

Comment: Look at *tickmarkPlacement*. You're using categories, so the default is "*between*". Change it to "*on*" to achieve the desired result.  Reference:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use, as **jlbriggs** suggested in comment, [`tickmarkPlacement`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) - xAxis' option. This will move grid lines and ticks.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ztsesk7f/

Other way might be to set [`pointPlacement`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<line>.pointPlacement) - series' option. This will move points.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7cc2ohe1/